# Very simple question: converting DVD/VOB to (say) AVI

Tags: video

I recently converted an old 90-minute VHS to DVD. I then copied the DVD files onto my PC: VIDEO_TS.BUP, VIDEO_TS.IFO, VIDEO_TS.VOB, VTS_01_0.BUP, VTS_01_0.IFO, VTS_01_1.VOB (1GB), VTS_01_2.VOB (1GB), and VTS_01_3.VOB (938MB). I can open VIDEO_TS.IFO with VLC media player and watch the entire video. No problem.

But when I try to convert the VOB files to AVI, I get problems. VTS_01_1.VOB only has nine seconds, and VTS_01_2.VOB only has ten seconds! VTS_01_3.VOB has only the last 26 minutes of the video. The software I've tried includes Windows Live Movie Maker, Convert VOB to AVI, and VOB to AVI: they all generate the same problems.

I just want the video in a single easy-to-watch file. Does anyone know what to do? Thanks.

Comment: That's a bad idea. You are converting the already-poor-quality video to the AVI format, known to be lossy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/). It's one of the best transcoders I know of, and have used it myself many times to convert DVDs to video files.

It is pretty simple and straight forward to use, but if you need any help/guidance [this page](http://www.winxdvd.com/blog/how-to-use-handbrake-convert-dvd-to-avi-100915.htm) covers pretty much all you need to know.

Have fun! And if you have any further doubts don't hesitate to comment.

Kevin.